# Select From CTE using AS? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I'm trying to convert a PostgreSQL into SQL Server. But this query doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? I tried to add a semicolon before WITH but no luck.

```
   SELECT 
      member_a AS you, member_b AS mightknow, shared_connection,
      CASE
         WHEN (n1.member_job_country = n2.member_job_country AND n1.member_job_country = n3.member_job_country) THEN 'country in common'
         WHEN (n1.member_unvan_id = n2.member_unvan_id AND n1.member_unvan_id = n3.member_unvan_id) THEN 'unvan in common'
         ELSE 'nothing in common'
      END AS reason
   FROM (
      WITH transitive_closure(member_a, member_b, distance, path_string, direct_connection) AS
        (SELECT 
             member_a, member_b, 1 AS distance,
             CAST(member_a as varchar(MAX)) + '.' + CAST(member_b as varchar(MAX)) + '.' AS path_string,
             member_b AS direct_connection
         FROM Member_Contact_Edges
         WHERE member_a = 45046 -- set the starting node

         UNION ALL

         SELECT 
             tc.member_a, e.member_b, tc.distance + 1,
             CAST(tc.path_string as varchar(MAX)) + CAST(e.member_b as varchar(MAX)) + '.' AS path_string,
             tc.direct_connection
         FROM Member_Contact_Edges AS e
         JOIN transitive_closure AS tc ON e.member_a = tc.member_b
         WHERE tc.path_string NOT LIKE '%' + CAST(e.member_b as varchar(MAX)) + '.%'
         AND tc.distance < 2
        )

   SELECT
       member_a, member_b,direct_connection AS shared_connection
   FROM transitive_closure
   WHERE distance = 2
  ) AS youmightknow
  LEFT JOIN Members AS n1 ON youmightknow.member_a = n1.memberID
  LEFT JOIN Members AS n2 ON youmightknow.member_b = n2.memberID
  LEFT JOIN Members AS n3 ON youmightknow.shared_connection = n3.memberID
  WHERE (n1.member_job_country = n2.member_job_country 
         AND n1.member_job_country = n3.member_job_country)
        OR (n1.member_unvan_id = n2.member_unvan_id 
            AND n1.member_unvan_id = n3.member_unvan_id);
```

Error I get:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
>   Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
>   common table expression, an
>   xmlnamespaces clause or a change
>   tracking context clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Here is the reference; [Graphs in the Database - SQL Meets Social Networks](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/09/07/graphs-in-the-database-sql-meets-social-networks/) - Look at the facebook suggestion part at the bottom of the article.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CTE declaration needs to go at the top. You can also have multiple CTEs declared and joined by commas rather than mixing CTEs and derived tables.

Try

```
;WITH 
/*First CTE declaration*/
transitive_closure(member_a, member_b, distance, path_string, direct_connection) 
AS
(   
     ...
),
/*Second CTE declaration*/
youmightknow AS
(
SELECT member_a, member_b,direct_connection AS shared_connection
FROM transitive_closure
WHERE distance = 2
)        
SELECT member_a AS you,
...
FROM youmightknow
```

Comment: thank you @Martin working like a charm now and @Michael Ludwig: thanks for the reference it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Move your CTE definition to the beginning of your SQL statement. The keyword `WITH` appears once at the beginning of your statement to introduce one or more CTEs, which may then be referred to in the following SQL. Take a look at this [CTE example](http://aaronakinsql.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/nested-common-table-expressions/), it will clear it up for you.